# Is System.Data.SqlClient Specific to SQL Server Only?

Tags: c#, sql-server, repository-pattern

This may be a basic question, but is System.Data.SqlClient Specific to SQL Server Only?

I would like to use the System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder as a method parameter to my repository interface IRepository.Find(), but don't want to use a SQL Server specific argument.
Is there a vendor-neutral version of the SortOrder enum?

For now, I am just using a string parameter called sortOrder which just takes the value "asc" or "desc" or just create my own enum.

Here is the implementation of the method in question:

```
public ICollection<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int pageNumber, int size, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy, string sortOrder, out int count, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] fetchSelectors)
{
    count = (this.DbSet as IQueryable<T>).Count(predicate);

    if (size < 1 || size > count)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
    }

    var maxPageNumber = (count + size - 1) / size;
    if (pageNumber < 1 || pageNumber > maxPageNumber)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageNumber");
    }
    if (sortOrder != "asc" && sortOrder != "desc")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("sortOrder");
    }

    var skipCount = pageNumber * size;
    var query = BuildQuery(predicate, fetchSelectors);
    query = sortOrder == "asc" ? query.OrderBy(orderBy) : query.OrderByDescending(orderBy);
    return query.Skip(skipCount).Take(size).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx), yes this is SQL Server specific.

> The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider
>   for SQL Server.

Collation will likely be provider-specific, although the semantics (ASC/DESC) are common.

Answer (score 2):

It is SQL Server - specific.

In general, I would recommend against taking a sort order in a `Find` method. Instead, I would provide a separate `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` methods, in a way LINQ does with `IQueryable<T>`. Moreover, if implementing `IQueryable<T>` is an option, that would be my first choice: you'd be able to "piggyback" on the knowledge the users of your library have accumulated over the years of using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is specific to SQL Server only.  You can easily make your own enumeration such as:

```
enum SortOrder
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection`.